# FFmpeg error - unspecified pixel format for pipe input

Tags: .net-core, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert stream into mp4 file using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -an -s 800x600 -q:v 31 output.mp4
```

Output:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55e63529aec0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3001 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pipe:0':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100   Duration: 00:03:03.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 3001 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @0x55e63529aec0] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

**What I've tried:**

to increase `analyzeduration` and `probesize` values in the command

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -an -s 800x600 -q:v 31 output.mp4
```

but I still have the same error.

Update:

```
ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -f mp4 output.mp4
```

this command with formmating stream as mp4 actually works with smaller files. I still have issues with bigger files. [I'm suspecting on dockerfile with specfic ffmpeg package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082725/dockerfile-install-newer-version-of-the-ffmpeg-package)

Comment: Have you tried to use `-pix_fmt` option? For example: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. Also if I notice that someone uses `-probesize` and `-analyzeduration` then their values are much higher than yours, for example: `-probesize 4G` and `-analyzeduration 10G` - maybe try these instead.

Comment: tried both, still the same issue

Comment: @user1765862 Thanks for updating with your solution: `ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -f mp4 output.mp4`.

Comment: Have you used `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before `-i pipe:0`? I would like to know also the result of the output for this command: `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4` and/or `ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -i pipe:0 -c copy output.mp4`. And in the end: have you tried to use `-probesize 4G` and `-analyzeduration 10G` with your working example for small files?

Comment: Considering `ffmpeg -input opts -input filename -output opts -output filename`... Usually if you set some opts on one side then you don't have to repeat them on the other side (they get auto-transferred over). Set both sides if there are differences like Like **input** is `-pix_fmt yuv422p` vs **output** of `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. Experiment on what gives you the best/nearest expected result

Comment: Also regarding `-c copy -pix_fmt yuv420p` the pixel format should be ignored by FFmpeg since **codec copy** will provide the pixel format from the codec data being copied. You can set `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before `-i pipe:0` if you know the input actually has that picture format. If you don't specify anything for input options then FFmpeg will try to analyze (and/or guess) the codec type/settings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **tell FFmpeg what codec format** (and/or settings) that your pipe data is using.
You didn't say what format your *"stream"* is using so here's some general tips:

- Apply format setting (including widths/heights, where needed like for raw RGB data).
- Use `-f` to specify a format.
- Use `-pix_fmt` to specify a YUV picture format (like 4:2:0)

For example if your stream to convert is in H.264 format (you won't need `pix_fmt` here):

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i - -c:v copy -f mp4 output.mp4
```

or can try as (where you don't need `-f` for MP4 output :

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i pipe:0 -c:v copy output.mp4
```

If your stream is raw RGB pixel data: 
(maybe you're generating a video by code / bitmap data at 30 FPS with `-r 30`).

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt argb -s 800x600 -r 30 -i pipe:0 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -an  -q:v 31 output.mp4
```

Hope it helps. Ask anything if you get a specific error.

Comment: The codec of the input is visible in the output code - it's `h264`. The thing that's missing is the pixel format of the input: `none`.

Comment: @Lex have you managed to solve this? I'm having the same issue.